# difference between pipe and comma delimiter in spark-scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Can someone tell me why do we have two separate ways of representing pipe(|) and comma(,). Like

```
sc.textFile(file).map( x => x.split(","))
```

for comma, and

```
sc.textFile(file).map( x => x.split('|'))
```

for pipe.

Keeping both in double quotes, its failing with pipe and comma is giving me correct result.

Below is the full code which I am running

```
package com.rakesh.singh

import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.log4j._
object MPMovie {
  def namex ( x : String) = {
   val fields = x.split('|')
   val id = fields(0).toInt
   val name = fields(1).toString
   (id , name)
  }
  def main(rakesh : Array[String]) = {
    Logger.getLogger("yoyo").setLevel(Level.ERROR)
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Movies").setMaster("local[2]")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val rdd = sc.textFile("F:/Raakesh/ml-100k/movies.data")
    val names = sc.textFile("F:/Raakesh/ml-100k/names.data")

    val mappednames = names.map(namex)   
    val splited = rdd.map(x => (x.split("\t")(1).toInt,1))
    //.map(x => (x,1))
    val counteachmovie = splited.reduceByKey( (a ,b )=> a + b).map( x => (x._2 , x._1))
    val mpm = counteachmovie.max()
   println(s"the final value of mpm is $mpm")
   mappednames.foreach(println)
    val finalname = mappednames.lookup(mpm._2)(0)
     println(s"the final value of mpm is $finalname")


  }
}
```

and data files are

movies.data
196 101 3   881250949
186 101 3   891717742
22  103 1   878887116
244 102 2   880606923

names:Data
101|Sajan
102|Mela
103|Hum

Comment: `"aa|bb".split("\\|")`

Answer (score 4):

There are two different `split` methods:

The `split(",")` method comes originally from [String.split(regex: String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-), it works with arbitrary regexes as separators, e.g.

```
scala> "helloABCworldCABfooBBACCAbar".split("[ABC]+")
res0: Array[String] = Array(hello, world, foo, bar)
```

The other `split('|')` comes from [StringOps.split(separator: Char)](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/StringOps.html#split(separator:Char):Array[String]), and is rather like a generic Scala-collection operation. It doesn't work with regex, but it works on all `StringLike` collections, for example on `StringBuilder`s:

```
scala> val b = new StringBuilder
b: StringBuilder =

scala> b ++= "hello|"
res2: b.type = hello|

scala> b ++= "world"
res3: b.type = hello|world

scala> b.split('|')
res4: Array[String] = Array(hello, world)
```

The "|" doesn't work with the first method, because it's a nonsensical "OR"-regex. In order to use the pipe `|` with the `split(regex: String)` version, you either have to escape it like this `"\\|"` or (often easier) to enclose it into `"[|]"`-character class.